# How to create Layout Topside ribbon on android app

Tags: java, php, android

I want to create a layout with ribbon for my android app layout but the ribbon goes behind the image immediately it fetches data / image from server. this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
        style="@style/RippleStyleBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_40">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_item_img"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_item_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/loading_placeholder"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_60" />

                <ImageView
                    android:text="RED"
                    android:id="@+id/down_ribbon"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_top_ad_right"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2px"
                android:background="@color/grey_5" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The first imageView above is the background The second Imageview is the ribbon and the third imageView is for the image gotten from the server.

My Question is how will i make image Ribbon come in front of the image after and before it fetches it from the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is that the ribbon imageView should come last since all of them are at the same RelativeLayout see the correct code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
        style="@style/RippleStyleBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_40">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_item_img"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_item_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/loading_placeholder"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_60" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:text="RED"
                    android:id="@+id/down_ribbon"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_top_ad_right"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2px"
                android:background="@color/grey_5" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```